# Reading out the direction and frequency of a point in the Matlab 2D DFT fft2() function

Tags: matlab, fft, octave, dft

I am getting familiarized with Matlab and the function `fft2()`. In this toy example, I am aiming at producing the 2D DFT of the following 256 x 256 png image:

[image]

To be able to understand the output easily, I try to convert this image into a 256 x 256 image, eliminating color information:

```
Im = imread('circ.png');
pkg load image
Im = rgb2gray(Im);
figure, imshow(Im)
```

After this bookkeeping preliminaries I run:

```
A = fft2(double(Im));
```

[image]

`A` is a 256 x 256 matrix from which amplitude and phase can be calculated.

**The question is how to extract the direction (theta) and frequency (e.g. pixels/cycle)?**

---

EXAMPLE COMPARING MATLAB AND IMAGEJ OUTPUTS AFTER SLEUTHEYE'S ANSWER:

[image]

**with ImageJ:**

```
Frequency = 10.24 pixels/cycle (25 cycles)
Theta (direction) = 16.26 degrees
Real part = -1.255
Imaginary part = 10.142
Phase = arctan(10.142 / -1.255) = -82.95 degrees
Magnitude = sqrt(10.142^2 + 1.255^2) = 10.2194
```

and **with Matlab:**

```
Im = imread('circ.png');
pkg load image
Im = rgb2gray(Im);

A = fft2(double(Im) / 255);
Ashifted = fftshift(A);
Ashifted(121,153)

i = 121;
j = 153;

center = size(A) / 2 + 1;
dx = (j - center(2)) / size(A,2);
dy = (center(1) - i - 1) / size(A,1);

direction = (atan2(dy, dx))
dir_degrees = direction * (360 / (2*pi)) 
frequency = 1 /sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

The output:

```
ans =  -1.2553 + 10.1425i
direction =  0.28379
dir_degrees =  16.260
frequency =  10.240
```

Comment: @Suever I think it's a misunderstanding because I'm using the same example: it is a different question, and I got a perfect answer to it by the same person who wrote a perfect answer to my prior question, which you are linking as identical. It wouldn't make any sense for me to post again the same question.

Comment: How is it different? It looks the same to me. You're trying to get the magnitude and the angle at a particular point

Comment: @Suever It is my understanding that there are 4 values describing a 2D DFT: the magnitude and phase (object of the previous question); and the direction (theta angle) and frequency (sometimes described as a vectorial quantity). These two last values are the object of the present question.

Comment: Right but you literally computed the direction and frequency in your previous question yourself.

Comment: @Suever Please check the answers by SleuthEye, and you'll see they are different.

Comment: I'm not saying they aren't different, I'm saying you didnt' need to ask another quesiton because you clearly already knew from your previous question.

Comment: @Suaver I did not, and that why I asked. I am a serious learner, and don't want to waste anybody's time. Please feel free to do whatever you feel you have to do. I don't care.

Comment: The title says Matlab, the first part of the question says Octave, and later example says Matlab.  It might be interchangeable for this example, but I'd recommend you be consistent regarding what tool you're using. There have been a number of cases of solutions being unique to one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192747/reading-out-specific-points-off-the-matlab-octave-fft2-function-output) which describe your use of [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/index.html) which provides direct readings of the direction and frequency parameters.

Let say you have a particular pixel `A(i,j)`, then the direction and frequency in pixels/cycle (as similarly obtained by ImageJ) can be obtained using the following:

```
center = size(A)/2 + 1;
dx = (j-center(2))/size(A,2);
dy = (center(1)-i-1)/size(A,1);

direction = atan2(dy, dx); % in radians
frequency = 1/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you very much for all your help. To be clear, the direction is in radians, and the `i` and `j` need to be entered manually before running your code, e.g. `i = 2` and `j = 3` to retrieve the direction an frequency at point `[2,3]` of `A`, correct?

Comment: I tried running the code on an example, and the output is different than ImageJ. I bet I'm doing something wrong, but I wonder if you wouldn't mind taking a look (I edited the OP with the output and code with both software platforms).

Comment: Actually, it's my bad. It looks like I was off by 1 on the `dy` computation.

Comment: @Toni Is that still a problem?

Comment: Not at all... Just fending off texts from volunteers... It works great. Ty! Where is the `- i - 1` on your edited formula coming from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139909/discussion-between-sleutheye-and-toni).